# picasso or glide doesn't display image

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I can load image URL but picasso or glide can't display them in imageView. any solution ? i tried every solution in stack overflow

```
String imageUri = photo.getPhotoURL().getRegular();
    Log.d("photo_log"," : "+imageUri);
    Picasso.get().load( imageUri).into(holder.photo);
```

and this is my logcat

```
 D/photo_log:  : https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633113089631-6456cccaadad?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwyNzc5MDJ8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTYzODEyNDQ3MQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080
```

I also put the URL directly into `.load()` but still doesn't show the image

Comment: Does your app request the `INTERNET` permission?

Comment: yes of course I checked every thing